# Recurrence relation through master's theorem and iterative method - different logarithm base

Tags: algorithm, recurrence

I did a binary search recurrence relation using master's theorem and one using the iterative method.  With the iterative method I got log<sub>2</sub>(n).  However, with the master's theorem it was case 2 which is log(n).

Is there a reason why the master's theorem doesn't have a base 2 for the logarithm, or am I just doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2):

These methods give an [asymptotic analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymptotic_analysis) using [big O notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation). And in big O notation we have:

O(logn) = O(log<sub>2</sub>n) = O(log<sub>10</sub>n) ...

In other words: the base of the logarithm does not influence the asymptotic analysis, and the outcomes you got are equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

**All logarithms are proportional**: for any logarithm bases b and d, and any strictly positive real x:

`log_b(x) = log_d(x) / log_d(b)`

If you are not concerned about a constant factor, then you can interchange logarithms.

**Example:** the number of bits required to write a number in base 2 is approximately proportional to the number of digits required to write that number in base 10. The proportionality constant is log_10(2) = 1 / log_2(10) ≈ 0.301. For instance, 999999 in base 10 has 6 digits, and is written `11110100001000111111` in base 2, which has 20 bits. You can verify that 6 = 0.3 x 20.